# Is this a good justification for why integration by substitution works?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, intuition, chain-rule

It is a well known fact that

$$ \int f'(g(x))g'(x)dx=f(g(x))+C $$

This follows directly from the chain rule. However, sometimes it is easier to perform the substitution $u=g(x)$:

\begin{align} u&=g(x) \\ \frac{du}{dx}&=g'(x) \\ du&=g'(x)dx \\ \therefore \int f'(g(x))g'(x)dx&=\int f'(u)du\\&=f(u)+C\\&=f(g(x))+C\end{align}

Ordinarily, one cannot simply multiply both sides of an equation by $dx$. After all, '$dx$' on its own is not even formally defined. Here is my attempt to justify why this is allowed:

> As well as knowing that $ \int f'(g(x))g'(x)dx=f(g(x))+C $, we also
> know that
>
> $$ \int f'(u)du=f(u)+C $$
>
> Note that this holds even when $u\neq g(x)$. However, the above fact
> becomes useful when we set $u=g(x)$, as $f(u)+C$ becomes $f(g(x))+C$.
> Knowing that $ \int f'(g(x))g'(x)dx$ and $\int f'(u)du$ evaluate to
> the same thing, we can say that
>
> $$ \int f'(g(x))g'(x)dx=\int f'(u)du $$
>
> when $u=g(x)$. Hence, $g'(x)dx$ can be replaced by $du$, without the
> value of the integral changing. Since differentiating both sides of
> $u=g(x)$ and multiplying by $dx$ yields the same result, it is safe to
> treat $\frac{du}{dx}$ as a fraction in this case.

I have two questions:

1. Is this justification good (or, at the very least, valid)? If it can be improved upon, how so?
2. Is there a more fundamental reason as to why $\frac{du}{dx}$ can be treated as a fraction? Is it something to do with how we can treat derivatives as fractions when using the chain rule?

Comment: I think it's more intuitive to go directly from $u=g(x)$ to $\mathrm du=g'(x)\mathrm dx$. The differential wrt $u$ is the differential wrt $x$ scaled by the differential in $g(x)$, i.e. the derivative (since as you take the limit, functions becomes approximately linear). I might be wrong but I believe that's where the notation $\mathrm du/\mathrm dx$ comes from.

Comment: *"Is there a more fundamental reason as to why $\frac{du}{dx}$ can be treated as a fraction?"*  Well, no: it's rather the ingenuity of its inventor, Leibniz, that it *behaves* in like one.

Comment: I don't think it is a consequence of the Chain Rule, it depends crucially on the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. If you are to get any sort of *proof* you have to sort out the $x$s; the LHS is free of $x$, the RHS is a function of $x$. I think all you are doing is juggling with the notation.

Comment: As an aside, it is not always true the $\int_a^b f'(x)\,dx=f(b)-f(a)$.  [See This on Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Volterra%27s%20function%2C%20named,derivative%20V%20%E2%80%B2%20is%20bounded%20everywhere)

Comment: Also, check out [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2973886/justification-for-notation-of-line-integrals/2975155#2975155)

Comment: @MarkViola I'm sorry but I don't quite follow. What I wrote was that $\int f'(x)dx=f(x)+C$. I don't understand how definite integrals come into this. It seems like a lot of users have made similar comments, so I am wondering if that's part of my confusion.

Comment: Not all derivatives of functions are Riemann integrable.

Comment: the phrase "Note that this holds even when $u\neq g(x)$" is not clear in the given context

Comment: Pherhaps this helps...I really enjoyed this video when first trying to understand substitution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CoJbL_quLSU&list=LLl23_bzq5JqaZVpRetJlNjg&index=4&t=0s