# Integration with Signed Lebesgue-Stieltjes Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, stieltjes-integral

Let $g$ be a continuous **(not need to be monotone)** function of bounded variation and $f$ be a measurable function. $m$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and $m_g$ is the **signed** Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure that $m_g((a,b]) = g(b) - g(a)$.

**Question:** Does $\int_a^{b}f(g(x))dm_g = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(x)dm$ hold when the integral of either side exists?

I can prove the above equality when g is monotone using the change of variable formula for **positive** measures in this post: [Is there a change of variables formula for a measure theoretic integral that does not use the Lebesgue measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152338/is-there-a-change-of-variables-formula-for-a-measure-theoretic-integral-that-doe).