# Dual operator on $C([0,2 \pi])$

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Consider $T:C([0,2 \pi]) \rightarrow C([0,2 \pi]) $
$$
T(f(x)) =e^{ix} f(x).
$$
Find dual operator $T^*: M([0,2 \pi]) \rightarrow M([0,2 \pi]) $.

---

Using the [Riesz representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) for $\mu \in M([0,2\pi])$ and definition of dual operator we can write 
$$
T^*\mu(f(x)) = \mu(T(f(x)) = \mu(e^{ix} f(x)) = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{ix} f(x) d \mu(x).
$$
How can I express $T^* (\mu)$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the change of variables formula for measures (see for instance this older StackExchange post:  [Is there a change of variables formula for a measure theoretic integral that does not use the Lebesgue measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152338/is-there-a-change-of-variables-formula-for-a-measure-theoretic-integral-that-doe)) to rewrite your last expression into the form $$\int_0^{2\pi}f(x) d\nu(x)$$ Obtaining something of the form $$\langle T^* \mu, f\rangle$$ should then allow you to define the operator $T^*$.