# Understanding $P(XY\leq c)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, definition, density-function

> Let be $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),P)$ a probability space and $X,Y$ two real valued absolutely continuous random variables, where $f_X$, $f_Y$ and $f_{XY}$ are the respective density functions.
>
> According to our definition the joint distribution function for $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ is given by
> $$
> P(X\leq x,Y\leq y)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^x\int\limits_{-\infty}^yf_{XY}(s,t)ds~\!dt.
> $$
> If $X,Y$ are independent then
> $$
> P(X\leq x,Y\leq y)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^x\int\limits_{-\infty}^yf_{X}(s)f_Y(t)dt~\!ds.
> $$

Now, let's consider $P(XY\leq 1)$ and $X> 0$. It is intuitve to come up with the integration limits that "surround" the respective area and simply say that
$$
P(XY\leq 1)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\frac{1}{x}}f_{X}(s)f_Y(t)dt~\!ds.
$$
However, I am wondering how to rigorously derive this result from the above definition of the joint probability distribution? In other words, how do I get a set of the type $\{X\leq x,Y\leq y\}$ that is equivalent to $\{XY\leq 1\}$ and $\{X>0\}$?

Comment: Your integral is not correct.

Comment: @AndrewZhang, thx I have edited it.

Comment: A joint density is usually *defined* to satisfy $P((X,Y) \in A) = \iint_A f_{X,Y}(s, t) \, ds \, dt$ for any region $A$.

Answer (score 1):

For the joint density function of $X$ and $Y$ we have (by the usual measure-theoretic definition):
$$P((X,Y) \in A) = \iint_A f_{X,Y} \,d\lambda_2$$
for all $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ (where $\lambda_2 = \lambda \otimes \lambda$  is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$). So
$$P(XY\leq 1, X>0) = \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{XY\leq 1}\mathbf{1}_{X>0}]=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\mathbf{1}_{xy\leq 1}\mathbf{1}_{x>0}f_{XY}(x,y)\,d\lambda_2(x,y)$$
From there, Fubini's theorem will give you the final form of the integral. We used the general fact that
$$\mathbb{E}[h(X,Y)] = \iint h(x,y)f_{XY}(x,y)\,d\lambda_2(x,y)$$
for all measurable functions $h:\mathbb{R}^2 \to [-\infty, \infty]$.

Comment: Let me add that the final formula is called change of variables in the measure theoretic context: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152338/is-there-a-change-of-variables-formula-for-a-measure-theoretic-integral-that-doe

Comment: hmm I am a bit confused...How does this answer help to understand that $P(XY\leq 1)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\frac{1}{x}}f_{X}(s)f_Y(t)dt~\!ds$ can be achieved by using our definition: $P(X\leq x,Y\leq y):=\int\limits_{-\infty}^x\int\limits_{-\infty}^yf_{XY}(s,t)ds~\!dt.$

Comment: @Philipp I guess what's confusing here is the fact that $$P((X,Y)\in A) = \iint_A f_{X,Y} \,d\lambda_2$$ since other than that, everything follows from Fubini and the change of variables. If so, then you can derive it from your definition by invoking the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorm.