For which $f$ do we have $\int_{−∞}^{+∞} f (x + m) \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{−∞}^{+∞} f (x) \, \mathrm{d}x$?
So, I want to believe that there is a theorem like so:
$$∀ m. \int_{−∞}^{+∞} f (x + m) \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{−∞}^{+∞} f (x) \, \mathrm{d}x$$
proof by infinity
Assume $∀ x. ∞ + x = ∞$.
$$\int_{−∞}^{+∞} f (x + m) \, \mathrm{d}x
\overset{\text{substitution}}=
\int_{−∞ + m}^{+∞ + m} f (x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\overset{\text{assumption}}= \int_{−∞}^{+∞} f (x) \, \mathrm{d}x$$
∎ Slick! But $∞$ is not a real number. I wonder if this can be formalized with some fancy «extended real numbers» kind of theory.
proof by principal value
Assume $∀ m. \lim_{a \to ∞}\int_{a − m}^{a + m} f (x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 0$.
$$\begin{align}
&\int_{−∞}^{+∞} f (x + m) \, \mathrm{d}x\\
\small{\text{(principal value)}}=
\lim_{a \to ∞}&\int_{−a}^{+a} f (x + m) \, \mathrm{d}x\\
\small{\text{(substitution)}}=
\lim_{a \to ∞}&\int_{−a + m}^{+a + m} f (x) \, \mathrm{d}x\\
\small{\text{(split at $a − m$)}}=
\lim_{a \to ∞}&\int_{−(a − m)}^{+(a - m)} f (x) \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{a − m}^{a + m} f (x) \, \mathrm{d}x\\
\small{\text{(linearity of limit)}}=
\lim_{a \to ∞}&\int_{−(a − m)}^{+(a - m)} f (x) \, \mathrm{d}x + \lim_{a \to ∞}\int_{a − m}^{a + m} f (x) \, \mathrm{d}x\\
\small{\text{(assumption)}}=
\lim_{a \to ∞}&\int_{−(a − m)}^{+(a - m)} f (x) \, \mathrm{d}x\\
\small{\text{(principal value)}}=
&\int_{−∞}^{+∞} f (x) \, \mathrm{d}x\\
\end{align}$$
∎ Nice! And it is plausible that a bounded function with finite total weight will have infinitely light tails. But how do I formalize this?
my question
So, for which $f$ is the above statement true? Is there a standard reference?
I found something called Glasser's master theorem, but it is formulated differently in different sources so I am not sure if it applies. I have no idea how to prove it anyway.

If you integrate f, it means that it is integrable (no way !), and this condition ensures that your formulae holds.

Which integral are you considering (Riemann, Lebesgue, ...)? How regular is your function?

@Maxime But how exactly does it ensure that?

Using Lebesgue theory. Use the change of variable for Lebesgue integrable functions.

@SeverinSchraven   I have no idea. Practically in my case $f$ is going to be a measure or even a probability measure, so I guess Lebesgue integration is appropriate.

This boils down to basic measure theory. See for example here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152338/is-there-a-change-of-variables-formula-for-a-measure-theoretic-integral-that-doe where $F$ is just a translation. To conclude you need that the Lebesgue measure is translation-invariant.

Alright. I was hoping there is an argument that does not involve measure theory. If measure theory makes this trivial, I guess I should learn measure theory.

I am a bit confused. If you are integrating against measure, than clearly you need measure theory. If this is only a question about improper Riemann integrals, then you can get away without any measure theory at all. That is why I asked about your setting.

@SeverinSchraven   To be honest, I have not really come to appreciate the difference between Riemann and Lebesgue integration yet. The whole Measure Theory thing seemed mysterious and far fetched so far. If there is a proof assuming $f$ is Riemann integrable, it would be good to know. If there is an even easier proof assuming $f$ is merely Lebesgue integrable, it would be good to know as well.

@IgnatInsarov If you do not know any measure theory, then it does not make much sense to write an answer based on measure theory. For improper Riemann integrals, it is fairly easy.

@SeverinSchraven   Believe in me! I catch up quick.

Improper Riemann integral: Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that the improper Riemann integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx$ exists. That means for every $a\in \mathbb{R}$ we have that the limits
$$ \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_a^R f(x) dx, \quad \lim_{R\rightarrow -\infty} \int_R^a f(x) dx $$
exist. In this case the improper Riemann integral is equal to
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx = \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-R+a}^{R+a} f(x) dx $$
for any fixed $a\in \mathbb{R}$.
This reduces the problem to show the change of variables for a proper Riemann integral. We have
$$ \int_{-R}^R f(x+m) dx = \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{2R}{N} f(m-R+ j \frac{2R}{N}) = \int_{-R+m}^{R+m} f(x) dx. $$
Putting things together, we get
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x+m) dx = \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-R}^R f(x+m) dx 
= \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-R+m}^{R+m} f(x) dx 
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx.$$
Lebesgue integral: Let's assume now that $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ (i.e. $f$ is Lebesgue integrable). The standard way to prove identities is to proceed as follows:
1.) Show that it holds true for indicator functions $f(x)=1_A(x)$.
2.) By linearity it holds true for $f$ being a simple function.
3.) Using monotone convergence it holds true for all nonnegative integrable function.
4.) Splitting into negative and positive part and using again linearity it holds for all real, integrable functions.
5.) Splitting into real and imaginary part it holds for all integrable functions.
Thus, the only thing one really needs to check is that our identity holds true for indicator functions. This means, the statement we want to prove is that
$$ \mathcal{L}(A) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_A(x) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_A(x+m) dx = \mathcal{L}(A-m),  $$
where $\mathcal{L}$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and
$$ A-m = \{a-m \in \mathbb{R} \ : \ a\in A\}.$$
This last equality is the fact that the Lebesgue measure is translation-invariant (see here Is Lebesgue measure translation invariant? for a proof).
Cauchy's principal value: Finally, we can interpret your integrals as a principal value with singularities at infinity. Namely, if you think of this expression as
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx = \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-R}^R f(x)dx. $$
In this case your identity does not hold. Consider the function $f(x)=x$. Then we have
$$ \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-R}^R x dx = \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-R}^R x dx = \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} 0 =0. $$
On the other hand, we have for $m>0$
$$ \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-R}^R f(x+m) dx
= \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-R}^R (x+m) dx
= \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-R}^R m \, dx = \infty. $$

Say $f (x) = x$. There is no $\lim_{R → ∞} \int_a^R x , \mathrm{d}x$ but there is $\lim_{R → ∞} \int_{−R}^{+R} x , \mathrm{d}x = 0$. I thought we can have $\int_{−∞}^{+∞} x , \mathrm{d}x = 0$ — but what you are saying is that it is not an improper Riemann integral, but rather some other kind of improper integral. Right?

@IgnatInsarov No, we cannot take $f(x)=x$. Neither for Lebesgue, nor for Riemann integration. I am not sure what kind of integral you are thinking of.

Ah, alright. I guess I should look into it separately.

@IgnatInsarov I have added a paragraph about the principal value (which might have been what you were looking for?). Anyhow, I personally think it is more useful to have a good grasp of Riemann and Lebesgue integration before turning to those obscure kind of integrals.

Fantastic, thank you! I had no idea there are such terrible problems with the principal value definition of improper integral.

@IgnatInsarov It is to be expected as the principal value definition fixes a certain way you are "going to infinity". If you shift you are changing the way you are integrating and given that nothing converges in the usual sense, there is little hope that the integral should behave nicely under perturbations.

+1 for discussion of principal value.  One reason that convergence of improper integrals is defined in this fussy way is so that it will have desirable properties, such as "substitution".
